# Lookup value from matrix of data Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet extract which has two tabs:

**tab 1** - Win Ranges

```
LeagueSizeMin   LeagueSizeMax   WinRangeID
1                    24            1
25                   49            2
50                   99            3
100                  199           4
200                  499           5
500                  999           6
1000                 2499          7
2500                 4999          8
5000                 9999         10
10000                19999        11
20000                NULL         12
```

**tab 2** - Prize Perc

```
League_WinRangeID   PositionMin PositionMax WinPerc
1                       1           1        40.00
1                       2           2        25.00
1                       3           3        15.00
2                       1           1        40.00
2                       2           2        20.00
2                       3           3        12.00
2                       4           4        8.00
3                       1           1        36.00
3                       2           2        16.00
3                       3           3        10.00
3                       4           4        8.00
3                       5           5        6.00
```

On tab 1 I ask for a league size and a position.  What I want to do is output the percentage in another box.  I have explored VLOOKUP but this is not allowing me to perform the <= and >= functions I need to get the unique value.

So using the example `league size = 29, Position = 2` this would return `20%` as `29` falls into `WinRangeID 2`.  The `position Min` and `position Max` can also be different values i.e. positions `10 - 19`

Does anyone have a solution or can provide direction to this complex VLOOKUP?

Comment: You said : "this would return 20% as 29 falls into WinRangeID 2." Can you explain this more clearly - it is by far "obvious" how you end up with 20% ..

Comment: and please add output against these inputs too...

Comment: So looking at league size = 29, this then falls into row two of the first table as the number 29 is between the min and max of this table.  This gives me the winrageID of two.  I want to then use this ID to reference the next table and and then check the position 2 within this range to five a percentage, in this case 20% in row 5 on table two

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the cases where the `Range_Lookup` parameter of the `VLOOKUP` function can be set to `True`.

Specifically, if you `Vlookup` the number 29 in tab 1, using a formula such as:

`=VLOOKUP(29,A1:C10,3,TRUE)`

The formula will return 2.

Note: this structure only interests itself in the minimum value. Setting the parameter to `TRUE` looks for an exact match. If not found, it selects the next lower value.

Comment: How can the result of this search then lookup then be used to look up the data on tab two as it will need to filter the table on the Winrage and then search within that range for the position between position min and max values?

Comment: Based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29213693/lookup-value-from-matrix-of-data-excel#comment46637612_29213693) comment, use this answer to get the first row, then use a `VLOOKUP` on the appropriate subset of rows on your second sheet to get your second number. (Note, having ranges on your first sheet is unnecessary - You only need Col B & C, and the last entry in B needs to be *HUGE*). Having ranges on your 2nd sheet is unnecessary, as well.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use an `Array Formula`. Using this type of formula, you'd enter it into the formula bar, then confirm it with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. The formula is: `=INDEX('Tab2'!D2:D13,MATCH(1,('Tab2'!A2:A13=VLOOKUP('tab1'!E1,'tab1'!A1:C11,3,TRUE))*('Tab2'!B2:B13='tab1'!F1),0))`  Note, the lookup values (are in cells E1 and F1, respectively, on Tab 1 [so, value 29 is in cell E1, and Value 2 for position is in F1])